# What's the benefit of re-trigger a custom event to another custom event?

Tags: javascript

For example, the following code:

```
this.notifyClosed=function(){this.trigger("uiSigninOrSignupDialogClosed")},

this.on(this.$node,"uiDialogClosed",this.notifyClosed) // <- what is the benefit of calling a function which is only to forward the event with another event name?
```

To clarify, the event name in the second line "uiDialogClosed" is also defined within that class (which the first line is included).  so, the steps the coder doing this

1. trigger an event name (a) in a function in that class,
2. capture that event name (a) in the same class,
3. and then dispatch to another function in that class,
4. then trigger another event name (b) in that class

what's the benefit of doing the those instead of just triggering event name (b) in step (1)?

---

Source code reference:

https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/init.c55682c6beb3d82a7317d5287646278649c9e765.js

Search 'this.notifyClosed' in the above source code. There are only 2 occurrence in that source code. And that exactly explains my question.

Comment: sure, source is minified.

Comment: This looks lime a provision for future events that would also trigger (b) after another (not existing yet) event (c) has been fired.